# Local Security policy in windows 7 - Only elevate executable files that are signed and validated

Tags: windows, security, winapi, windows-7, uac

I'm writing a windows application that is embed with a manifest considering UAC in windows 7. On testing the application I found that , if "only elevate executable files that are signed and validated" option in local security policy is enabled, the application installation doesnt get started.

In this case I want my executable get signed.how to sign an executable? Does the executable should pass WHQL certification? or can I use self signed certificate to sign my executable? What does Microsoft says in this?

> What are the other ways to start my executable even if the option -
>   "Only elevate the executable files that are signed and validated" in
>   local security policy is enabled.Can I make it possible by any of the
>   manifest options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to Authenticode sign your binaries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There's no point in doing this with a self-signed, as this will not be a trusted cert on other machines (and therefore fail validation). You'll need to buy yourself a certificate from the certificate "racketeers" (A.K.A. trusted authorities).

Comment: What are the other ways to start my executable even if the option - "Only elevate the executable files that are signed and validated" in local security policy is enabled.Can I make it possible by any of the manifest options?

Comment: @user1317084: That would kinda' defeat the point of that policy. "Can I elevate?" "No, you're not safe" "ohh, pretty pleace, I'm safe, honestly" "oh, go on then" "muhahahahah!!!"